# Step back and forth in DataInputStream in Java

Tags: java, datainputstream

I am reading a video file using DataInputStream. I am then using a byte array to read data  one by one for each frame and then displaying them consecutively. My question is, what if I wanted to see a previous frame again, or a future frame for that matter? Is it possible to step back in the stream, or is any other way possible?

Comment: Hold data with buffering

Comment: why don't you maintain stack of processed frame data I mean buffer?

Comment: i can store the data..but i was kind of hoping to avoid that since the total disk space required for storing byte arrays for all frames would be gigantic..that's why the query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a memory mapped approach for this. If you know what the size of each frame is, and it's fixed, there is no reason why you can skip (forward/backwards) and simply map in that frame (or sequence of frames).

Comment: Exactly. The whole point of the stream interfaces is one-way, sequential access (thus the name).

Comment: @Nim that's what i don't know, yes the frames are constant in size, and i could have gone backwards/forward if the stream was in the form of an array, but i think it isn't (or is it?). please enlighten me how can i do that. I of course know the exact length of the byte array used for each frame.

Comment: @ParagGoel, a memory mapped file is exactly that, it allows you to "map in" a block from the file into memory and access that like an array. Let's say each frame is 1024 bytes, to "read" the first 10 frames, you would map a block of 10 * 1024 bytes from the file at the offset 0, then to read the next 10, from the offset 10240, etc. You should read about memory mapped file access first, I think it will be enlightening..

Comment: Oh alright, I guess I should read about it first then and then come back if it still doesn't solve it..

Answer (score 0):

As a "simple" solution, you *could* wrap your `DataInputStream` with a [`PushbackInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html). However I wouldn't rely on that, but write my own buffering strategy. Why don't you just cache the last frame in memory?

Comment: i should be able to access any frame which i have accessed till now, not only the immediately previous one, that's why i think it is useless to cache the previous frame. But it looks like the PushbackInputStream is promising..

Comment: @ParagGoel, it requires you having all the bytes to push back. I.e. if you wanted the frame 10 frames back, you need to keep all that data to push back into the stream.

Comment: so I guess I will have to do it the hard way then, either store everything in memory or spend time to re-compute..

Comment: @Parag Goel: Based on your input, you should separate the `InputStream` from the "frame buffer". That means, the `InputStream` is transparent to your application, which will only deal with a frame buffer, that loads the next frame if not already done, but can skip to the previous frames that are already loaded.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen Yes, this looks like the best solution under the circumstances, thanks for the tip. :-)